# How to find the $x^2+y^2=?$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $ x$ and $ y$ are complex numbers, such $x+y=1$ and $x^{20}+y^{20}=20$, Find the sum of all possible values $x^2+y^2$

I find this problem answer is $-90$, But my methods is very very ugly, and I think this Problem have some nice methods.Thank you everyone.

Comment: yes, I'm sure.Thank you

Comment: OP, so $x$ and $y$ are allowed to be complex numbers?

Comment: yes,@PatrickLi,

Comment: @vadim123, $x,y$ is complex...

Comment: $x$ and $y$ can be real too, for example, x -> -0.161586, y -> 1.16159

Comment: sorry, I have edit

Answer (score 11):

This is quite doable without calculus if you can be clever with the polynomials. Rewrite $x^2 + y^2 = (x+y)^2  - 2xy = 1 - xy,$ and note that for any pair $(x,y)$ satisfying the relations, we must have that $x$ is a root of the polynomial $p(x) = x^{20} + (1-x)^{20} - 20 = 2x^{20} - 20 x^{19} + 190 x^{18} - ... -19 .$ Since $y$ is uniquely determined by $x,$ we know that there exist exactly $20$ such pairs. Summing over all $20$ pairs reduces to $20 - 2\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{20} x_i y_i = 20 - 2\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{20} x_i (1-x_i) = 20 - 2\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{20} x_i  + 2\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{20} x_i^2$ The first sum can be calculated with the coefficients of $p$ using the first of [Vieta's Formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Basic_formulas)  - these are obtained by factoring the polynomial and comparing coefficients. Its value is $- \frac{-20}{2} = 10$ - cancellation reduces the computation to only the last sum.

Note $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{20} x_i^2 = [\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{20} x_i ]^2 - 2 \displaystyle\sum_{i < j} x_i x_j = 10^2 - 2 \cdot (190/2) = -90 ,$ where I've now used the first and second Vieta formulae. This last step is also the first nontrivial [Newton Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Mathematical_statement).

Comment: have some wrong, there are possible $p(x)=2x^{20}-20x^{19}+\cdots-19=(x-x_{1})^{r_{1}}\cdots$$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Let $xy=c$

So, $x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy=1-2c$

$x^3+y^3=(x+y)^3-3xy(x+y)=1-3c$

On multiplication, $(x^2+y^2)(x^3+y^3)=(1-2c)(1-3c)$

$\implies x^5+y^5+x^2y^2(x+y)=1-5c+6c^2\implies x^5+y^5=1-5c+5c^2$

On squaring, $ x^{10}+y^{10}+2(xy)^5=(1-5c+5c^2)^2$

$\implies  x^{10}+y^{10}=1-10c+35c^2-50c^3+25c^4-2c^5$

On squaring, $ x^{20}+y^{20}+2(xy)^{10}=(1-10c+35c^2-50c^3+25c^4-2c^5)^2$

$\implies  x^{20}+y^{20}=4c^{10}-100c^9+\cdots+1-2c^{10}$

$\implies  2c^{10}-100c^9+\cdots+1=20\implies 2c^{10}-100c^9+\cdots-19=0$

This is a $10$ degree equation in $c=xy$

Using [Vieta's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html), $\sum xy=\frac{100}2=50$

$\implies \sum x^2+y^2=10-2\sum xy=10-2\cdot 50=-90$

Comment: @math110, we just need $x^{20}+y^{20}$ to be constant, right?

Comment: ,I don't think so

Comment: your methods forget why $xy$ No heavy root？ mean this $2c^10-100c^9+\cdots+1=(x-c1)^{r_{1}}(x-c_{2})^{r_{2}}\cdots (x-c_{10})^{r_{10}}$

Comment: @math110, Does  "heavy root" mean "repeated roots"? If yes, Vieta formula takes care of that, right? With you example, $r_1\cdot c_1+\cdots+r_{10}\cdot c_{10}=\frac{100}2=50$